# Django navigation with dropdowns

Tags: python, django

This is my templatetag file:

```
@register.inclusion_tag("site/nav_bar.html")
def nav_bar():

    nav_bar = Page.objects.filter(navbar=True, parent=Page.objects.filter(slug="home"),).exclude(slug="home",).order_by('order')[:20]
    return {
        "nav_bar": nav_bar
    }
```

Navbar html:

```
<ul class="left">
  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  {% for nav in nav_bar %}
  <li><a href="/{{ nav.slug }}">{{ nav.title }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Part of Models.py

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=True,
        )
    slug = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        unique=True,
        blank=True,
        )
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        ("Page"),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        )
```

How do I add dropdowns to the main navigation bar, I'm not talking about html/css just getting the loop inside (I'm using foundation by zurb)

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking here.

Answer (score 0):

You currently have your menu designed as a tree with pointers to the parent (also knows as an [Adjacency List model](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)). To calculate a tree, you need to perform a sql query for each level to build a tree (this is really inefficient). That article above gives you some strageties for how to query your data to build a tree.

You might want to look at storing your menu as a higher order data model like an MPTTModel from [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/).

I would recommend checking out any open source project that implements a menuing system

[Django-CMS](https://github.com/divio/django-cms) is an example and has a very robust menu system. They store pages as MPTTModels and then build a tree querying from their pages. The menu app then uses that structure from the pages to render content out through template tags

This should give you idea about how to implement it yourself